# Daemon on embedded Linux device using BusyBox be written in C or as a script

Tags: c, embedded, daemon, busybox

Should a daemon on an embedded device using BusyBox be written in C or as a script?

All the examples I have seen use `#! /bin/ash` at the top of the file and that is for scripting? But in the device I'm writing to has only complied C files (I think) and symbolic links in `/usr/bin`.

Every way I try to compile a C file with `#include </bin/ash>` (e.g. `gcc -Wall -o daemon_busybox daemon_busybox.c`) I get error after error report in `/bin/ash`:

> /bin/ash:174:1: error: stray ‘\213’ in program
> /bin/ash:174:1: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
> /bin/ash:174:1: error: stray ‘\273’ in program
> /bin/ash:174:1: error: stray ‘\204’ in program
> /bin/ash:174:1: error: stray ‘\342’ in program

Note I have set this: `/bin/ash -> busybox`

Any ideas which way I should go?

Update:

I've been given the task trying to see if a daemon can be run on a small device that runs Linux (2.6.35-at-alpha4) and Java (SE Embedded Runtime Environment) with very limited memory (i.e. a 10 second wait to get `java -version` to report back).

Two weeks ago I didn't know much about daemons — only knew the word. So, this is all new to me.

On my development machine I have built two different daemon files, one in C and one as a script. Both run very nicely on my Linux machine.

But because of the very small size of the target device there is only BusyBox (no `/lib/lsb/init-functions`). So I'm trying to build a third daemon file. I believe it should be written in C for this device, but all examples for BusyBox point to scripting.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run a compiled program as if it was a shell script.

Comment: You realize C programs are compiled with e.g. GCC first, right? Also, what does Java have to do with any of this? I'm not sure who's more confused right now; you or I.

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart - thanks for carefully reading my post (^.^)v

Comment: what exactly does this daemon do?

Comment: Right now it's just a test to see if we can run a daemon on our device.

Comment: The device makes a lot connections between the system it is monitoring and the main server. There's a big memory demand, especially during updates.

Comment: So, my boss is hoping to move (some or all)  these to the kernel and call them via cron. I don't see how that will help.
This is all new to me and if I can get a daemon running on the device I doubt I can make 3G connections from level 1.
(Note: I don't know much about how the whole system works - I'm just a contract worker hired at the last minute in hopes the project will more or less meet its promised release date.)

Answer (score 1):

Once your question is edited so that the file name you're trying to `#include` is visible, the problem becomes self-evident:

```
#include </bin/ash>
```

This tries to make the C compiler include the binary of `busybox` (via the symlink `/bin/ash`) into the code to be compiled.  The average binary is not a valid C source file; this is doomed to failure.

Perhaps you simply need to drop that line — the C compiler stands a better chance of working if it is given header files and source files to compile.  Maybe there's more work needed; we don't have enough information to help there.

Many daemons are written as C programs, but a carefully written shell script could be used instead.

---

> Personally, I would like to do this as a script (I've never liked C). But on the device everything in the `/usr/sbin` folder looks like a C file. So, the conservative coder in me says C is the way to go. I know: ask the guys developed the device — but they're long gone. Right now my daemon is just a test (i.e. `printf("Hello World\n");` ). I'm trying to get `printf` passed to Busybox. But so far I cannot get this file to compile. I just need a simple daemon in C to start.

OK; your C code for that should be just:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Save it in `hw_daemon.c`.  Compile it using:

```
gcc -o hw_daemon hw_daemon.c
```

If that won't compile, then you've not got a workable C development environment for the target machine.  If that will compile, you should be able to run it with:

```
./hw_daemon
```

and you should see the infamous 'Hello World' message appear.

If that does not work, then you can go with the script version instead, in a file `hw_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/ash
printf "Hello World\n"
```

You should be able to run that with:

<sup>*Predicted output — not output observed on a machine.*</sup>

```
$ ash hw_script.sh
Hello World
$ chmod +x hw_script.sh
$ ./hw_script.sh
Hello World
$
```

If neither of those works at all, then you've got major problems on the system (maybe Busybox doesn't provide a `printf` command workalike, for example, and you need to use `echo "Hello World"` instead of the `printf`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Dropping the #include is not a problem, provided there is another way to pass calls to busybox.

Would PATH work?

Comment: #! /bin/ash gives me 

invalid preprocessing directive #!

Comment: What is in your `daemon_busybox.c` file?  Is that C code or a shell script?  If it is C code, then you compile it as a C program.  If it is a shell script, then no compilation is necessary (but you do want a shebang as the first line, probably).  If you need to run a Busybox program, nominally you could use `system()` or perhaps `popen()` and `pclose()` — this is not uncommon in a C program that needs to run some other program.  But it really isn't clear what you have in `daemon_busybox.c`, which makes it hard to guess what you need to do.

Comment: On the whole, you should create a script if you can, rather than a C program.  I've not actively used Busybox so I can't readily tell you what is involved in creating a C program to run in a Busybox environment.

Comment: Personally, I would like to do this as a script (I've never liked C). But on the device everything in the /usr/sbin folder looks like a C file. So, the conservative coder in me says C is the way to go. I know - ask the guys developed the device - they're long gone. 

Right now my daemon is just a test (i.e. printf("Hello World\n"); ). I'm trying to get printf passed to Busybox. But so far I cannot get this file to compile. 

I just need a simple daemon in C to start.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. 

hw_daemon.c - Hello World - works perfectly fine on my development machine.

However on the target device I get 

1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

As I've said, the device is small. Also it already uses Busybox. There's no <stdio.h> on the device. It's just a sensor for remote monitoring of solar farms.

The hw_script.sh worked fine on the target device, which I'm glad to see. But there's that twitchy feeling that says everything else is in C, so this daemon should be too.

But for speed - which is generally faster - C or scripting?

Comment: For whatever reason, it seems you'll need to use a script, then, rather than a C program.  At execution time, a C program is usually faster than a script, but when developing the code, scripting is usually faster than C programming.  However, speed is usually less important than "does it work" — if you can get the script working, use it until it is shown to be far too slow to be acceptable.