# How can I call a dynamic library in C?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dll

OS: [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr)

Write two .c files named *dtest1.c* and *dtest2.c*.

#### File *dtest1.c*

```
int p = 2;

void print()
{
    printf("this is the first DLL test!\n");
}
```

#### File *dtest2.c*

```
int p = 3;

void print()
{
    printf("this is the second DLL test!\n");
}
```

Then, compile them to get two files named *dtest1.so* and *dtest2.so*:

```
gcc -O -fpic -shared -o dtest1.so dtest1.c
gcc -O -fpic -shared -o dtest2.so dtest2.c
```

Write a .c file named *dtest3.c*.

#### File *dtest3.c*

```
#include "dtest1.so"

int main ()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

So far now, everything is good. There isn't any error (only a warning).

Then:

```
gcc -o dtest3 dtest3.c dtest1.so
```

#### Error:

```
In file included from dtest3.c:1:0:
dtest1.so:17:1: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
dtest1.so:17:2: error: stray ‘\260’ in program
   ......
   ......    /*omit too many similar information */
dtest1.so:18:2: error: stray ‘\212’ in program
dtest1.so:18:2: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
In file included from dtest3.c:1:0:
dtest1.so:18:956: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
In file included from dtest3.c:1:0:
dtest1.so:18:2: error: stray ‘\244’ in program
dtest1.so:18:2: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
In file included from dtest3.c:1:0:
dtest1.so:18:980: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
dtest1.so:18:982: warning: null character(s) preserved in literal [enabled by default]
dtest1.so:18:982: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
In file included from dtest3.c:1:0:
dtest1.so:18:2: error: missing terminating " character
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: You don't `#include` compiled libraries, you `#include` C source code, normally placed in a file with `.h` extension.

Comment: thank you for your words ,you inspired me to solve this problem.^_^

Comment: This is a common error (including object/binary files). What is the canonical question?

Comment: Inadvertently included object/binary files (thus not real duplicates): *[Daemon on embedded Linux device using BusyBox be written in C or as a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759855/)* and *[Cannot use 'sourceCpp' from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547750/cannot-use-sourcecpp-from-a-file#comment134363065_48547750)* (the titles are not descriptive wrt. to this kind of error and thus the bodies must be read)

Comment: The warning probably contains "`warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`"

Comment: The ***actual*** first error more likely contains the signature for ELF (0xFF, octal 177), "`dtest1.so:1:1: error: stray ‘\177’ in program`" (tested on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver)). This is in line with the symptom from the [former reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547750/cannot-use-sourcecpp-from-a-file#comment134363065_48547750) (though not the exact same cause); see also its [***"Linked"*** questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/48547750?lq=1) (upper right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraries are compiled code, not (textual) source code. `#include` simply inserts the contents of given file, so it should be source code. You have to link your library by passing it as argument to the linker.

Read [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) for more.

Comment: thank you~but the page is ugly,and the information is too hard to me.^_^

Comment: @Lie Zang - The page is not "ugly", and the information is valuable.  Please read it.  ALSO: Please "upvote" and "accept" Youka's reply.

Comment: @LieZang Then i have to tell you: back to basics. You can search in web, there're many more tutorials about this task and maybe one fits your progress.

Comment: @Youka  thanks for your advice ❤ I will keep it up O(∩_∩)O

Comment: @paulsm4  the page is ugly ╭(╯^╰)╮

Answer (score -3):

Writing a **.h** file like this:

**dtest1.h**

```
void print()
{
    printf("this is the first dll test!(this is a .h file)\n");
}
```

Modify the **dtest3.c** file, delete the #include **"dtest1.so"** and **add** a

```
#include "dtest1.h"
```

And compiled that:

```
gcc -o dtest3 dtest3.c dtest1.so
```

Some info to me:

```
In file included from dtest3.c:1:0:
dtest1.h: In function ‘print’:
dtest1.h:3:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
     printf("this is the fist dll test!(this is a .h file)\n");
     ^
```

Try to run dtest3:

```
./dtest3
```

Get info like this:

```
this is the fist dll test!(this is a .h file)
```

But I really confused it, so try again:

```
$ vi dtest1.h
```

Modify the file like this:

**dtest1.h**

```
void print();
```

And modify dtest1.c:

```
$ vi dtest1.c
```

**Add** a line:

```
#include "dtest1.h"
```

And compiled it to get a new .so file:

```
gcc -O -fpic -shared -o dtest1.so dtest1.c
```

Compiled the dtest3.c file:

```
gcc -o dtest3 dtest3.c dtest1.so
```

NO WARNING NO ERROR.....HAPPY

```
$ ./dtest3
./dtest3: error while loading shared libraries: dtest1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

New problem....T_T ,but the result of search by google tell me :

*system can't find the library, even though i provide the path of dtest1.so when i complite the dtest3.c ,but this information didn't writed into the  dtest3*

Do some test:

```
$ ldd dtest3
```

/* This command will tell the file's depended library */

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1d3d7000)
dtest1.so => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6e9914c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6e99532000)
```

/* Sadness flood my mind...... */

But a webpage tell me a method to solve it:

```
$export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

The system will find that path at first time, so can insured the dtest1.so could be found.

Now try again:

```
$ ./dtest3

this is the first dll test!
```

**Congratulations!**

Comment: Instead of `$export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` you could simply update the link directories cache of your system by program `ldconfig`.