# Why do I get weird stray errors with file 'cxxopts.hpp' and Meson + Ninja build?

Tags: c++, ninja, meson-build

I'm currently working on [this](https://github.com/studentenherz/FOCUS/tree/f0c43fd43a36837aa64d457fe9283cef4028face) project. I'm using [cxxopts.hpp](https://github.com/artpaul/cxxopts) in order to parse cli options, but since I added it, I get some error that I now list how to reproduce:

1. Build the project

   ```
   meson build
   cd build
   ninja
   ```
2. Everything good so far, it builds without any errors.
3. I can change anything other than `test/vector.cpp` and `test/random.cpp` (that are the places where I'm using `cxxopts.hpp`) and build with `ninja` without any problems.
4. Then when I edit `test/vector.cpp` or `test/random.cpp` and do `ninja` these error appears:

   ```
   [1/4] Compiling C++ object test/random.p/random.cpp.o
   FAILED: test/random.p/random.cpp.o
   c++ -Itest/random.p -Itest -I../test -I../include -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wextra -Wpedantic -O0 -g -MD -MQ test/random.p/random.cpp.o -MF test/random.p/random.cpp.o.d -o test/random.p/random.cpp.o -c ../test/random.cpp
   In file included from ../include/cxxopts.hpp:43,
                    from ../test/random.cpp:6:
   test/vector:1:1: error: stray ‘\177’ in program
       1 | <U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0003><U+0000>><U+0000><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000> F<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><90><91><U+0015><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000>8<U+0000><U+000D><U+0000>@<U+0000>(<U+0000>'<U+0000><U+0006><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0004><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>@<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>...
       (a very lengthy error up to 400 MB in a file)
   ```

How can I fix this or why does this happen in the first place?

Comment: It seems one of your executables is called `vector` and you are adding include path with that executable and including an executable file with `#include <vector>`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks! This solved it! It seems like a very dumb mistake.

Comment: Nah. This has some subtlety to it. A dumb mistake is swapping `i` and `j` in a `for` loop or trying to eat a can of Coke.

Comment: "[ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)" is a hint. Here is another one where the compiler to chew on binary data: *[Daemon on embedded Linux device using Busybox be written in C or as a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759855/daemon-on-embedded-linux-device-using-busybox-be-written-in-c-or-as-a-script)*

Comment: Here is one where a build system is involved: *[Android NDK build errors, \221, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065790/android-ndk-build-errors-221-etc)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [pointed out by KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73410284/why-do-i-get-weird-stray-errrors-with-cxxopts-hpp-and-meson-ninja-build#comment129640776_73410284) in their comment, this error emerged from a name collision between the standard library `#include <vector>` and the binary `vector` I was creating from `vector.cpp`.

Changing the name of my binary solves the issue.

The desired behavior can be also achieved by setting the option `implicit_include_directories` to `false` like this:

```
vector = executable('vector', 'vector.cpp', include_directories: incdir, implicit_include_directories: false)
```

Comment: Is there any way of avoiding this without renaming my binary name?

Comment: You could change the output directory. If all of the generated files go into a bin folder, your vector becomes bin/vector and no longer collides. Plus separating the source and output is generally good from a sanitation standpoint.

Comment: @user4581301 I'll search how to do that. Thing is that's the default behavior of meson, it does separate code from binaries I don't know why it includes the binaries folder.